# Why is it "jedermann" but not "niemannd" or "jemannd"?

Tags: etymology

How come it is "man" in some indefinite pronouns, and "mann" in others? Why is it this inconsistent?

Comment: Expecting consistency in language, especially in orthography, actually is a bit moot.

Comment: I know of no German word where n before d is doubled, so one could argue that writing niemannd is inconsistent.

Comment: @tofro in German maybe. There are languages where orthography makes sense (Turkish, Finnish,...)

Answer (score 10):

The German words *man* and *der Mann* and the parts *man* or *mann* contained in words like *jedermann* and *jemand* derived all from the same root, which is same root where the English word *man* and the part *man* inside of *woman* and *human* comes from:

- Old High German (8th century): **man**
- Old English (about the same era): **mann**
- Proto Germanic (common root of all Germanic languages): **mann**

The spelling of this word changed many times between *man* and *mann* (and later also its capitalized version in German) over the centuries and it changed different in different variations of germanic languages, and at some time this word merged with other words or fragments (**wo**man, jeder**mann**), and then this new words developed independently from the original ones. Or to say it shortly: It just happened accidentally.

This is a phenomenon that we can see also in other words: The German word for bread is *»Brot«*, but not long ago (150 years or so) it was *»Brod«*, and so there are many people with the surname *Brodschneider* (which means: *bread cutter* or *bread slicer*), and I know an old bakery in Graz, where I was born with the inscription "Brod und Semmeln" engraved in the door beam.

Another example is *Geld* (money) which shifted between *Gelt* and *Geld* (or *gelt* and *geld*) over the centuries, and so we today have *Geld* with *d* but *Entgelt* and *gelten* with *t,* although all these word derive from the same root. (Btw: The english words *guild* (the write's guild) and *guilty* derive from the same root end exhibit the same d/t-variation.)

The reason for all this is, that we have an identical (man/mann) or a very similar (brod/brot; geld/gelt, guild/guilt) pronunciation, the spelling of which is not so clear, and so different versions of the spelling have evolved, and as different variants of these words have evolved, they have evolved independently. And for German, I can say that the very first time that spelling was standardized was in 1876, so only about 150 years ago, and then it was reformed in two major steps in 1901 and 1996, and also in smaller steps at other times. But before 1876, spelling was more or less free.

Comment: _"The German word for bread is »Brot«, but not long ago (150 years or so) it was »Brod«"_ — so *this* is why we have *бутерброд* instead of *бутерброт* in Russian! I've wondered about this for a long time, since it made no sense to me to change an unvoiced final consonant to a voiced one when borrowing a word.

Comment: Wow, really? There is a word *бутерброд* in Russian language? My translator (DeepL) says it means *sandwich*, which is **two** slices of bread made from wheat flour, with some cream, slices of sausage, cheese, tomato, lettuce and sometimes slices of egg or similar ingredients in between. So a sandwich is a rich meal. But the German word *Butterbrot* actually just means **one** slice of bread (usually dark bread made from rye flour with a crispy crust) and just some butter on it (maybe a pinch of salt), nothing else. So, what is a Russian *бутерброд* really?

Comment: The one with two slices is сэндвич, see e.g. [here](https://xn--b1algemdcsb.xn--p1ai/crossword/1853676) or [here](https://pudov.ru/articles/interesnye-fakty/sendvich-buterbrod-istoriya-i-fakty/#:~:text=%D0%91%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0,%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0.)

Comment: Actually, even Wikipedia has [an article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4) about бутерброд. The Russian version of Butterbrot is actually generalized to arbitrary stuffing, not restricted to butter. The English version of the Wikipedia page is called "open sandwich".

Comment: I don't understand Russian, I just can read Cyrillic letters. The images in the [wikipedia article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Бутерброд) show food, that we call *»belegtes Brot«* in German. A *belegtes Brot* (one slice with sausage, cheese or what ever) is different from a *Butterbrot* (one slice with butter only) and different from a *Sandwich* (two sliced with sausage or cheese etc. between). The English translation of *belegtes Brot* could be *topped bread* or *covered bread,* but obviously they call this also a sandwich in English.

Comment: Images: [Butterbrot](https://www.lamuehla.at/bilder/DSC_0327.jpg) - [belegtes Brot](https://files.billa.at/fg/thema7/20190901_10_l.jpg) - [Brötchen (in Austria)](https://www.hnuta.at/wp-content/uploads/klassik-hnuta-catering-600x401.jpg) - [Brötchen in Germany = Gebäck in Austria](https://www.genussregion-oberfranken.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Broetchenvielfalt-aus-Oberfranken01.jpg) - [Semmel (exists mainly in Austria)](https://shop.baeckerei-obauer.at/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Semmel-1-von-1.jpg) - [Wurstsemmel](https://media.marktjagd.com/6636342_742x457.jpg) ...

Comment: ... [Sandwich](https://images.eatsmarter.de/sites/default/files/styles/1600x1200/public/puten-gemuese-sandwich-216219.jpg) - [Burger](https://www.ebbing-tm.de/fileadmin/redakteure/bilder/rezepte/air-fryer/burger/burger-air-fryer7.JPG)

Comment: @Ruslan This seems frightfully close in both form and meaning to [_smørrebrød_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smørrebrød) in Scandinavia, which is roughly equivalent to _belegtes Brot_, though nowadays mostly more elaborate and fancy and mainly served in restaurants. _Smørrebrød_ can be described as being _(højt) belagt_ ‘with (high) toppings’, which fits with the German term _belegtes Brot_. (The less elaborate type shown in the _Butterbrot_ image above would be simply known as _en macka_ in Swedish or _en mad_ [lit. ‘a food’] in Danish.)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Well, the Wikipedia article says basically the same as you: _"In the dictionaries of the Russian language the word «бутерброд» borrowed from German is noted no later than the last third of XIX century, but the original «Butterbrot» in German to this day still means exclusively «bread with butter», and if it also has a piece of sausage, cheese, ham etc., then it'll be named «covered bread» (german "belegtes Brot") or «шту́лле» (german "Stulle").

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It looks like smørrebrød is a separate concept, at least there's a Russian Wikipedia article [Смёрребрёд](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D1%91%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B4). I hadn't heard of it before though, and it's explicitly described in this article as a traditional Danish dish (unlike бутерброд, which is no longer considered a foreign dish).

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, it’s a very traditional thing especially in Denmark, where it’s considered an unofficial national dish; but it’s roughly the same thing, and historically, the Danish term also referred to bread (usually dark rye bread) with toppings in general. Norwegian _smørbrød_ is more generic as well. The point was really that ‘butter-bread’ can seemingly be applied to rather a broad range of eatables: plain bread + butter (German); bread + any topping (Russian, Norwegian); bread + elaborate, festive toppings (Danish).

Comment: @Ruslan: The word *»Stulle«* is used only in Germany (or pars of Germany?). It is not used in Austria and I think that Bavarians won't use it too. Germany and Austria use different standardvariations of German, and the food & kitchen vocabulary is the most divers part. I guess that more than 50% of words used for food in Austria are unknown in Germany, and about the same amount of terms used in Germany are known, but not used in Austria.

Answer (score -1):

The spelling of *man* and *Mann* is consistent with pronunciation, but the difference is *phonotactic* or *prosodic* and not *phonemic*.

The pronoun is *unstressed* when *enclitic*, "Das kann man mal so machen." contracted *kam-ma-ma-machn*. This and similar phrases are likely the original construction which dictate the pronoun's underlying phonology.

The noun on the other hand is usually *stressed* on the first syllable and it bears conjugation, which dictates the *phonotactics* of the underlying stem. "So machen die Männer das." Since the vowel is not long, the *geminate* spelling is preferable in order to indicate a short stressed accent in the noun and to indicate that the medial consonant becomes *ambisyllabic* because of the *maximal coda onset principle*, *Män‧ner*.

Suffice to say that German spelling is not entirely consistent, but it is of course useful to distinguish inclusive *man* from masc. *Mann*. This is audible when somebody stresses that the common noun is actually intended, "Mann kann", by means of *prosodic* stress. This has lead to alternatives using any common noun as indefinite pronoun, *Frau kann*, *Mensch kann*, which is true to the fact that the distinctions just described are typically not realized.

I am not at all sure of the details, or how much this reflects the original situation. The cognate *Mensch* shows a different vowel. Old English *mann*, pl. *menn*, indef. pron *man* (normalized spelling) makes the same difference although "This noun was inflected as a consonant stem, but the daughter languages disagree on the form of the nominative singular." – Also, it's not entirely clear if this relates to *human* and *(Bräuti)gam* (en.WT). Chances are the story of the pronoun is no less complicated, while it is widely agreed that the Indo-European pronomina are exceedingly difficult to analyze.

---

en.WT: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/mann-